# how to remove matching elements in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have developed an app that post jobs that users near you have posted. When you apply to a job, that jobs gets posted in mongodb and loaded in a section of the app, where you can manage your posted,applied and completed jobs. The issues that I have is that, when the job is posted in the applied section, it stills shows in page where you can apply.
On page load, an api call gets the applied jobs and the jobs near me. Each job has an id so I saved them in arrays so that I can compare each values from both applied jobs ids and jobs near me ids and if they match then I would remove that specific job from the jobs that are near me using splice. So that jobs that are already have applied to won't show up with jobs that I've not already applied to.

```
 let jobsN = this.allJobsNear;
 let appliedId = [];
 let jobsNearId = [];
 for(let i=0; i<jobsN.length; i++){

   jobsNearId.push(this.allJobsNear[i]._id)

 }
 for(let i=0; i<applied.length; i++){

   appliedId.push(this.appliedJobs[i]._id)

 }
 console.log(jobsNearId)
 console.log(appliedId)
jobsNearId.filter(el,i)=>{
  if(el === appliedId[i]){
    return i;
  }
}) 

        this.allJobsNear.splice(i,1)
```

```
i is the index, and allJobsNear is an array of objects. So I want to remove all jobs from near me if I've already applied to it.

appliedIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
jobsNearMeIds = [9,7,8,1,2,3]

If jobs near me ids have any id from appliedIds, return its index in jobsnearmeid and remove it.
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: how specificicly?? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Give us a sample array, and the expected output of applying your code to that sample array. (what's `this.allJobsNear` going to be, and what's the result going to be?)

Comment: what is `applied` ?

Comment: also there are syntax errors in the sample code. please post real code and expected behavior.

Comment: I've added a bit more details to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to need is

```js
const nearButNotApplied = this.allJobsNear.filter(({
  _id: nearId
}) => !this.appliedJobs.some(({
  _id: appliedId
}) => appliedId === nearId));
```

---

**Demo**

```js
const allJobsNear = [{
  _id: 1
}, {
  _id: 2
}, {
  _id: 3
}, {
  _id: 4
}]
const appliedJobs = [{
  _id: 3
}, {
  _id: 1
}]

const nearButNotApplied = allJobsNear.filter(({
  _id: nearId
}) => !appliedJobs.some(({
  _id: appliedId
}) => appliedId === nearId));

console.log(nearButNotApplied)
```